# How to create a new instance of PostgresSQL on OS-X 10.8 Server

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x

After upgrading my MacMini home server from OS-X 10.7 (Lion) Server to OS-X 10.8 (ML) + Server.app, I saw PostgreSQL 9.1.4 was released.

Unfortunately, the setup process for PostgreSQL 9.1.4 has created these brand new databases: `collab`, `webauth`, `postgres`, `tempalte0`, `template1`; all the other databases and roles created by me seem to have been deleted!

To better understand what has happened:

```
> Which postgres

OSX 10.7.4: /usr/bin/postgres
OSX 10.8: /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin/postgre

$PGDATA is now on:

OSX 10.7.4: "/var/pgsql"
OSX 10.8 "/Library/Server/PostgreSQL/Data"
```

After the update the `/var/pgsql` folder is gone.

Since I do not want to repeat this experience in future updates, I think it is a good idea to create my database on a separate cluster/instance.

How would advise me from here?

- Is there any other way to avoid losing my databases?
- Where and how should I create my own databases without interfering with Apple's databases?
- How can I configure and start a second instance of PostgreSQL on the same OS-X server?

Comment: Is it at all remotely possible that you have two instances running?

Comment: @swasheck definitely, only one instance running, checked by:  `ps -ef | grep postgress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"all others databases and roles created by my own are lost!"
```

I can't speak to the best practices for creating a new database, but as part of the Mountain Lion Server upgrade all of the "old" Postgres data should have been backed up to a subdirectory under `/Library(/Server?)`  Unfortunately as soon as I discovered this I moved-and-renamed the directory for safekeeping so I don't have the exact name!

I have a completely separate install of Postgres that I built myself for webapp purposes, but I certainly wouldn't call what my approach a "best practice". Largely what I did was build a "stock" install using a very similar set of configure parameters as Apple did (discovered by running `pg_config`) but with a different install location and default port setting. Following that I coptied-and-tweaked `/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postgresql.postgres.plist` and that's worked fine for me so far.

Comment: Thanks you for the support, `/Library/Server/Previous` it's a very usefull hint, for example I found the old plists in `/Library/Server/Previous/System/Library/LaunchDaemons` and the old PGDATA in `/Library/Server/Previous/private/var/pgsql/`. Shame `Library/Server/Previous/Library/Server/PostgresSQL/Backup` is empty (btw: I had not activated TimeMachine). Now I'm wondering that maybe it would be possible to restart, even the old instance (9.0.4) possibly on another port.

Comment: The idea of having a completely separate install of Postgres I think it's great, nevertheless a checklist or link to some pretty good story that explains how to do it step by step would be very welcome.
The problem primarily is: how to determine which path on filesystem to use to be sure that the next system updates do not impact on our instance.